# jquery/html/css making a image appear in the middle with an opaque background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi guys im new with web programming using html, css, javascript and jquery. i have this code:

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My test Site</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssTest.css"> 
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "divMain">
<div id="div1">
    <a href="#" title="Image1"><img src = "1.jpg" disabled="disabled"></a>  
    <a href="#" title="Image1"><img src = "2.jpg" disabled="disabled"></a>
    <a href="#" title="Image1"><img src = "3.jpg" disabled="disabled"></a>
</div> 
<div id="div2">
    <a href="#" title="Image1"><img src = "4.jpg" disabled="disabled"></a>
    <a href="#" title="Image1"><img src = "5.jpg" disabled="disabled"></a>    
</div>         
</div>
<div id="div3">
    <div class="myCanvas" width=100% height=100%; ></div>               
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
            $(".myCanvas").fadeIn();
            $(".myCanvas").html ($(this).html());
    }); 
});
```

CSS :

```
body{
background-color: grey;
}

#div1,#div2{
    border:solid;
    border-color: red;
}

#div1 img{
position: relative;
border: solid;
border-color: blue;
margin:5px;
z-index:1;
}

#div2 img{
position: relative;
border: solid;
border-color: blue;
z-index:1;
}

#div3{
background-color:black;
position: relative;
position-align: center;
top:-500px;
z-index:2
}

.myCanvas{
position: relative;
background: solid;
background-color: grey;
opacity: 0.5;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display: block;
z-index:3;
}
```

what I am trying to do is whenever i click on an image i would like to make the image appear in the middle with an opaque background that will be covering the other images.

Thank you guys for the help and sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/); it gives you the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

HERE you can find the solution :)
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tx74X/)

HTML

```
<div id="privacy">OPEN ME</div>
<div id="bgrprivacy"></div>
<div id="privacyopen">
I'M OPEN!!
</div>
```

CSS

```
#privacy{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#999;
    font-size:12px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#privacyopen{
    display:none;
    background:white;
    height:30%;
    width:50%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index:101; 
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding:20px;
}
#bgrprivacy{
    display:none;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#privacy").click(function(){
        $("#privacyopen").fadeIn(); 
        $("#bgrprivacy").fadeIn();
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        /*$("header").css("z-index", "1");*/
    }); 
    $("#bgrprivacy").click(function(){
        $("#privacyopen").fadeOut();    
        $("#bgrprivacy").fadeOut();
        $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
        /*$("header").css("z-index", "1");*/
    });     
});
```

Ps: it contains some code that you don't need it because I forgot to delete it :) ( I did this for my website! )